# What DocumentRoot to use?

Tags: apache2, rails, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app set up in a directory named "testapp". But when I run an apache2ctl configtest it tells me the Document Root is incorrect. Is there anyway I can check what the document root should be. At the moment I am given an error message saying the document root does not exist.Any help is welcome and thanks in advance.

```
DocumentRoot ***/home/rails/testapp/public***
```

Comment: I don't rails but what does your apache config file say?